# I can't login to my Django app when debug is set to False

Tags: python, django, apache, authentication, debugging

Short Story: I get locked out of my Django app when Debug is set to False.

Long story:

**Case 1 (the first time it happened):**

1. I enter my login info, but It just redirects to the login page.
2. I restart the server, try to login, and it works fine, I get in.
3. a few hours later I come back, log out, try to log back in and I can't. It just redirects to the login page.

**Case 2 (I figure out how to provoke the login failure):**

1. I restart the server and am able to login to the site.
2. I log in and log out several times, everything is fine.
3. I go to a non-existing page and get a server error.
4. I log out and try to log back in, and I can't, just get redirected back to the login page.

**Case 3 (I can't provoke the login failure with Debug set to True):**
1. I restart the server and am able to login to the site.
2. I log in and log out several times, everything is fine.
3. I go to a non-existing page and get a traceback.
4. I log out and log back in, everything works.
5. I wait and play around with it and can't get the login to fail while in Debug mode.

Please help!

Comment: If `DEBUG` is set to `True`, Django will return a `technical_404_response` with traceback.
Otherwise, it will try to invoke your `resolve404` callback function.
So this is probably where you should give us more details.

Comment: Epic error description, but totally useless... If the problem really doesn't occur with `DEBUG=True`, then look for specific settings that you have made. For example, I have `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = not DEBUG` in my site settings, which means I can only log in to the production server over HTTPS, not over HTTP. I recommend to use [sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) to see errors that occur in the `DEBUG=False` case (unless you can't login to sentry, either :D).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a custom 500 error handler set up? Is that doing something weird with the session, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Here is what I did to fix it:

I realized the cookie session was saved twice... I don't know why but after many changes a finally get working... just set

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'something'
```

and thats all.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was if I set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` then I can't login in `http` mode.

I had to change it to `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False`

Maybe you had this too?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this is related to errors in admin classes requiring the devserver to be restarted to continue.

As nothing is being reportedm I would try removing all of your admin.py definitions and just use the basic admin.site.register(SomeModel) for everything and seeing if it still happens, then add them back in until it re-occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `urls.py` file imports **everything** from `django.conf.urls.defaults.`

You may have explicitly imported certain methods such as patterns and include (as I did to combat PyDev's 'wild import' warning messages). 
As a result, crucial statements that assign Django's default handlers to 404 and 500 HTTP error codes will be omitted. 
This is obviously undesired and leads to the odd behavior described in the question.